# Pasar queryset como argumento a una url en Django 2

Tags: django, django-urls, django-views

Tengo un problema cuando quiero pasar una QuerySet como parámetro a una vista pero es opcional, no siempre lo paso.

Este es mi código:

urls.py:

```
path('categorias/', cms_views.category_list, name='category_list'),
path('categorias/filtrar', cms_views.category_filter, name='category_filter'),
```

view.py:

```
def category_list(request):
    #pagination and other tasks

    return render(...)

def category_filter(request):
    #filter objects from form

    return redirect('cms:category_list', elements)
```

He pensado en:

- Pasar los elementos filtrados como parámetro a la vista.
  `def category_list(request, elements=None):` pero entonces me da erro cuando no paso parámetros, no se como debo hacer la url como por ejemplo en este otro caso `path('categorias/<int:id>/editar', cms_views ...)` que es un entero.

Alguien puede echarme una mano ?
Gracias.